# Get public posts of users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I made an application that gets a fit permission and then can access the friends list.

so I have all the ids of the friends.

In addition, I have the `user token` and the `app token` of my application.

**there is an option to get the public posts of each friend?**

If it was a page, I can do something like:

```
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=[page-id]&format=json
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: You tagged the graph API but using a link like that wouldn't be using the graph API. Which one is it you're trying to do?

Comment: I was trying to do both things:
1) https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=[user-id]&format=json
2) graph.facebook.com/[user-id]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use graph.facebook.com/[user-id]/posts with any valid access token.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/